# How to disable the generation of stderr and stdout output files of Sikuli?

Tags: robotframework, sikuli

I integrated the sikuli server with robot framework.When running tests using the robot framework, i get output files generated by the robot and other output files(stderr, stdout) generated by the sikuli server.
What should i do to disable the log functionnality for sikuli?

This is for a windows 7 platform with python 2.7, robot framework 3.1.1 and sikuli library 1.1.2.

Comment: about sikuli library 1.1.2 you should be more precise: Is it SikuliX?

Answer (score 1):

If it is SikuliX:

- no chance to achieve what you want with 1.1.2 and an easy option
- with 1.1.2 you have to write a Java wrapper, that catches the stdout/stderr from the server.

If you are willing to upgrade to SikuliX 1.1.4, then you have an additional command-line option -q, that should suppress all output.

If you try that and still get buzz on stdout/stderr, then please report as precise as possible - I am willing to fix it asap ;-) (preferably on Launchpad)

RaiMan from SikuliX